# Solr Sunspot Production environment setup issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am trying to setup solr sunspot search in production mode.

I have followed the below tutorial and got success in setting up tomcat-solr server running.
http://www.arborisoft.com/how-to-install-apache-solr-4-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/

I ran

```
rails generate sunspot_rails:install
```

and configured the config/sunspot.yml file.

For development mode I used 'sunspot_solr' gem(which is not advisable for production mode) and got this command working.

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

When I removed this gem

it's giving me following error

```
  Note: This task has been moved to the sunspot_solr gem. To install, start and
  stop a local Solr instance, please add sunspot_solr to your Gemfile:

  group :development do
    gem 'sunspot_solr'
  end
```

I have tried adding this to Rakefile:

```
require 'sunspot/solr/tasks'
```

when I run the following command

```
bundle exec rake app:sunspot:solr:start
```

I am getting the following error

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sunspot/solr/tasks
```

I am using rails 4.

I don't know what I've missed. I have searched for the solution in and out of stackoverflow. But I couldn't get any reference. Even if I find any since I am a rails noob, I couldn't understand what they are talking about. any solution will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the path to **solr/default in config/sunspot.yml** file for production mode or any other defined modes.
These are some terminal commands which could follow to solve your problems:

1. **`ps aux | grep solr`** to get solr process ID 
   through this you can check which server id is running and which one is in your sunspot **pid file.**
2. **`sudo kill <ID>`, `<ID>`** is the ID you found from 1
3. **`rm -r <path/to/solr>`**, remove the solr directory inside your project to remove all of previous indexes
4. **`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`**
5. Change the path to **`/solr/default`** inside **`config/sunspot.yml`**
6. **`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`**

this link can also help in understanding problem and issues:https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/492